# Could you *be* any more metaphorical?

Tags: riddle, knowledge, wordplay

The following, apparently random list of seemingly random nonsense is a metaphorical interpretation of something that exists in the real world.  What is it?  As always, go line by line.  But once you figure it out, you'll have everything you need to write the solution.

> The current endeavor is not a genre, it is mass murder
>
> Your were torn from the respirator
>
> You were brought up to date
>
> Like half of a starlet or a whole amputee
>
> You wore vestments
>
> And played Dracula
>
> You scurry down the lane
>
> Defenseless, unhidden
>
> Concealed canine hunters for profit
>
> The statues pursue you with murderous intent
>
> I shall pacify an acquaintance
>
> Hasten hither, my child
>
> Veni, vidi, cessavitque
>
> Take leave of the flora
>
> Lest you fall ill 'mongst the murk
>
> They're mutts, bejeweled
>
> John Samhain is, at present, a snow leopard
>
> Who dwells above a vault
>
> Lift in disrepair, hemp brings him down
>
> So he prowls the macadam with Cheetah
>
> A tartlet nears with The Specials
>
> She wears no grin, but Salvador's accessory
>
> Nostalgic, chocolate chip cookies
>
> Destroyed and quadriplegic, yet the boxers are unwavering
>
> Annus belbus in the dog days of summer
>
> Strut next to the beach;  hasten to the trench
>
> "In the Year 2525", a hipster goes solo
>
> Pain is inevitable, try to live through the night

Minor hint:

> Rather Orwellian, isn't it?

Enormous, gigantic, probably ruins everything hint:

> The riddle's solution is best friend to both sexes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an interpretation of

> The David Bowie song, Diamond Dogs (btw the *probably ruins everything* hint was the key) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_Dogs_(song).

The current endeavor is not a genre, it is mass murder

> This ain't rock'n'roll. This is genocide!

Your were torn from the respirator

You were brought up to date

> As they pulled you out of the oxygen tent 
> You asked for the latest party

Like half of a starlet or a whole amputee

You wore vestments

And played Dracula

> With your silicone hump and your ten inch stump, Dressed like a priest you was, Todd Browning's freak you was 
> (Tod Browning directed the 1931 Dracula film with Bela Lugosi
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dracula_(1931_English-language_film))

You scurry down the lane

Defenseless, unhidden

Concealed canine hunters for profit

> Crawling down the alley on your hands and knee, I'm sure you're not protected, for it's plain to see, The diamond dogs are poachers and they hide behind trees

The statues pursue you with murderous intent

> Hunt you to the ground they will, mannequins with kill appeal

I shall pacify an acquaintance

Hasten hither, my child

> I'll keep a friend serene 
> Oh baby, come unto me

Veni, vidi, cessavitque

Take leave of the flora

Lest you fall ill 'mongst the murk

They're mutts, bejeweled

> Well, she's come, been and gone. 
> Come out of the garden, baby 
> You'll catch your death in the fog 
> Young girl, they call them the Diamond Dogs

John Samhain is, at present, a snow leopard

Who dwells above a vault

Lift in disrepair, hemp brings him down

So he prowls the macadam with Cheetah

> The Halloween Jack is a real cool cat 
> And he lives on top of Manhattan Chase 
> The elevator's broke, so he slides down a rope 
> Onto the street below, oh Tarzie, go man go 
>  (Samhain is another term for Halloween, Jack is often what John's are called, Tarzan was friends with a Cheetah )

A tartlet nears with The Specials

She wears no grin, but Salvador's accessory

Nostalgic, chocolate chip cookies

Destroyed and quadriplegic, yet the boxers are unwavering

> Meet his little hussy with his ghost town approach 
> Her face is sans feature, but she wears a Dali brooch 
> Sweetly reminiscent, something mother used to bake 
> Wrecked up and paralyzed, Diamond Dogs are stabilized 
> The Specials had a hit with "Ghost Town". Salvador Dali.

Annus belbus in the dog days of summer

Strut next to the beach; hasten to the trench

"In the Year 2525", a hipster goes solo

Pain is inevitable, try to live through the night

> In the year of the scavenger,the season of the bitch 
>  Sashay on the boardwalk, scurry to the ditch
> Just another future song, lonely little kitsch 
> (There's gonna be sorrow) try and wake up tomorrow
> (Belbus is Latin for Hyena (http://latin-dictionary.net/definition/6268/belbus-belbi). *In the year 2525* is a song about the future.)

Minor Hint:

> The song has a post apocalypic setting, reminiscent to some of the novel: 1984. According to Wikipedia this was the intention of Bowie on the Album of the same name: "Thematically, it was a marriage of the novel Nineteen Eighty-Four by George Orwell and Bowie's own glam-tinged vision of a post-apocalyptic world." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_Dogs

Major Hint:

> A __ is a man's/girl's best friend.

The genuine article:

> http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=36lWAcY9IXE

Comment: Excellent.  By the way, Tarzan was friends with Cheetah, not "a" cheetah.  Cheetah was actually an ape.  :)

Comment: Also, can you post a link to the video of this in a spoiler block quote?  If this Q&A turns someone on to it, so much the better.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=36lWAcY9IXE

Comment: Minor hint:  the original idea for the album was to make a rock adaptation of *1984*:  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KByxC7B9WH0

Comment: I added some info on the 1984 link, and added a link to Wikipedia article for the song, I'd rather leave the Youtube link to the video in the comments, as I've not had chance to open it myself yet.

Comment: Did you see the clue about best friends, think "Dogs and diamonds - I get it!", or did you think "Dogs and diamonds - I'll google that!"?

Comment: It was the former, probably prompted also by the various dog synonyms in the puzzle (mutt, dog, canine hunter), and the general dark theme (destroyed, disrepair, murderous intent). I know the song and the tune, and lyric fragments, but had to search for the lyrics for 90% of the clues.

Comment: It isn't urgent, but if you're worried about the contents of the video being NSFW/violation of policy, and how that might affect you, I would happily add it to your answer in an edit, with a formal declaration of my own responsibility for the contents.  "If anything untoward is in it, I am to blame, no one else", etc.  Or I could try to find one posted by Bowie's official YewToobs account.

Comment: Or we can just leave it here.

Comment: I think I'd just leave it as a comment, but not quite sure why, and I wouldn't roll it back. Maybe I always suspect that the video will have been taken down by the time anyone clicks on it, or not be available in half the countries, and that a group of angry puzzlers, complete with coloured hats, blindfolds and a multitude of execution devices, will come chasing me down for giving them false expectations.