# Yes, I *can* be more metaphorical

Tags: riddle, wordplay

Same deal as [previous post](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/23539/could-you-be-any-more-metaphorical).  One real world source; answers must explain each line and what they all mean when put together.

> Additionally amongst the mortality, while the final several cadavers reclined, decaying in the slick high street, the Venetian blinds raised 2.54 cm in Sobriety Structure, aloft on Rustlers' Knoll, and magenta aberrant orbs gaped below on Covet Metropolis.   Zero additional large tires.
>
> Syphonaptera the magnitude of rattus sipped on rattus the magnitude of felis catus.  And 500 score humanoids divided into minute clans, pining for the most elevated of the pure towers.  Similar to groups of mutts attacking the window facades of adore-yours-truly street.
>
> Tearing and re-enveloping mustela, and glimmering sterling vixen, currently leggings.  Hereditary emblem of corundum and fractured beryl.  At some time in the near future.
>
> The era of the carbon allotrope hounds.

Minor Hint:

> The scheme used here is very simple.  "Look, up in the air - it's Superman!" would be "Gaze, above amongst the breathable gases - it's Kal-El!"

Major Hint (Use only in case of emergencies):

> It has yet to happen, but it's already a myth.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mystery guest is:

> Future Legend by David Bowie

Additionally amongst the mortality, while the final several cadavers reclined, decaying in the slick high street,

> And In the Death, as the last few corpses lay rotting on the slimy thoroughfare

the Venetian blinds raised 2.54 cm in Sobriety Structure, aloft on Rustlers' Knoll

> The shutters lifted an inch in temperance building, high on Poacher's Hill

and magenta aberrant orbs gaped below on Covet Metropolis.

> And red mutant eyes gazed down on Hunger City

Zero additional large tires.

> No more big wheels

Syphonaptera the magnitude of rattus sipped on rattus the magnitude of felis catus.

> Fleas the size of rats sucked on rats the size of cats

And 500 score humanoids divided into minute clans,

> And ten thousand peoploids split into small tribes

pining for the most elevated of the pure towers.

> Coveting the highest of the sterile skyscrapers

Similar to groups of mutts attacking the window facades of adore-yours-truly street.

> Like packs of dogs assaulting the glass fronts of Love-Me Avenue

Tearing and re-enveloping mustela, and glimmering sterling vixen, currently leggings.

> Ripping and rewrapping mink and shiny silver fox, now legwarmers

Hereditary emblem of corundum and fractured beryl.

> Family badge of sapphire and cracked emerald

At some time in the near future.

> Any day now,

The era of the carbon allotrope hounds.

> the year of the Diamond Dogs

It is

> a spoken piece that introduces the bleak, post-apocalyptic future setting, leading into Diamond Dogs, the song of the previous question.

Comment: Awesome!  You might want to add explanations/definitions of the more obscure words - taxonomic terminology, mineralogy terms, maybe even "covet" ~ "hunger".  And I will give you my firstborn if you insert a link to the song from the YewToobs:  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Q7ABB8h7KA

Comment: But by no means are you obligated to do so.